# external POST request to update on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am working in .net webforms and am submitting something to an external web service via .ashx which then returns a POST request with parameters to my .aspx page. I am having trouble figuring out how to get that data back on my page.

I understand that `Request.QueryString["parameterName"]` should get anything sent as a querystring, but how can I then take that information and, say, put it in a label on the page in my browser.

Basically I want this: user is on .aspx page, clicks a button, processing happens externally and information from the POST request from the webservice is then displayed on the screen for the user on the same .aspx page.

I assume this involves and needs some ajax - I just am not quite comfortable enough with it to know how to do it and if what I am doing is right.

Any help would be much appreciated!

thank you in advance,

syd

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: so the service I am trying to use is Twilio, although I think the service is arbitrary. Everything has to be done on a live webserver, because the service won't work on localhost, so I cannot debug. I would like to start just by verifying that the POST request is even coming back at all, but I can't do that without being able to debug. 

I tried getting `Request.QueryString...` and setting a label.text equal to it on Page_Load, but that does not seem to fire when I believe I am getting the POST request, so then I figured I would take one step back and try and see if the POST is coming at all

Comment: Then I realized... how could my page in the browser refresh after getting the POST request without using ajax, although I am not exactly sure how to implement that. Is there some way with ajax to just wait for a POST request with a certain query string in it and then display the information from that string on the page whenever it comes, like an event listener??

Comment: Use `request.Form` instead of `Request.QueryString` to get parameters passed by POST and not in the querystring part of the URL. For AJAX, there are many, many examples online and will depend on your framework, eg. here's one for ASP.NET Web Forms: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: thank you for the `request.form` top. In terms of ajax... thanks for the link as well. I am not quite clear if I need it though. In general, if a POST request is directed at my .aspx page and I want to take a value from it and change a label.text value on my page, does that label have to be in an updatepanel? or can it just be a label on the page?